# Java function parameters from Restful API generated by mustache

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, mustache, swagger

I have this WebService API mustache file from swagger:

```
{{>generatedAnnotation}}
{{#operations}}
public class {{classname}}ServiceImpl extends {{classname}}Service {

{{#operation}}
  @Override
  public Response {{nickname}}({{#allParams}}{{>serviceQueryParams}}{{>servicePathParams}}{{>serviceHeaderParams}}{{>serviceBodyParams}}{{>serviceFormParams}}{{#hasMore}},{{/hasMore}}{{/allParams}})
  throws NotFoundException {
      foo(...)
      return Response.ok().entity(new ApiResponseMessage(ApiResponseMessage.OK, "foo")).build();
  }
{{/operation}}
```

what is generated is a Restful API:

```
@Override
public Response findPets(List<String> tags,Integer limit) throws NotFoundException {
    foo(...)
    return Response.ok().entity(new ApiResponseMessage(ApiResponseMessage.OK, "foo")).build();
}
```

The ">serviceQueryParams" etc. are seperate mustache files and look like:

```
{{#isQueryParam}}{{{dataType}}} {{paramName}}{{/isQueryParam}}
```

What i want is to call a function (foo) that takes the same parameters as in the generated API methods:

```
public Response findPets(List<String> tags,Integer limit) throws NotFoundException {
    foo(tags, limit);
    ...
```

another example:

```
@Override
public Response addPet(NewPet pet) throws NotFoundException {
   foo(pet);
   ....
```

I have the foo function already defined in java, but i need to edit the mustache file so that the code will be generated correctly.

Comment: It would probably be easiest to create new partials that follow the same model as ">serviceQueryParams" but do not output the data types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [api.mustache](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/modules/swagger-codegen/src/main/resources/JavaJaxRS/api.mustache#L51) file as an example, you can simply update your `api.mustache` file like such:

```
foo({{#allParams}}{{#isFile}}fileDetail{{/isFile}}{{^isFile}}{{paramName}}{{/isFile}}{{#hasMore}},{{/hasMore}}{{/allParams}});
```